# Python - Greatest Common Intersection of lists

Tags: python, list, nested, intersection

I would like to create a new nested list out of two given nested lists (with unique items in each list), so that the new nested list is the greatest common intersection of both lists.

An example hopefully helps to make my question clear:

```
    old1 = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9]]
    old2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[6,8,10]]]
    new  = [[1,2],[3],[4,5],[6,8],[7],[9],[10]]
```

Order is not important, so using sets may be useful.

Does anybody have an idea? Any help will be appreciated!

__

OK, so obviously, the easiest to get the greatest common intersection is

```
    new1 = filter(None,[list(set(o1) & set(o2)) for o1 in old1 for o2 in old2])
    print new1
    [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [7], [8, 6]]
```

If you want to include integers which appear only in one of the old lists, you can add them afterwards:

```
    a,b = set(sum(old1, [])), set(sum(old2, []))
    c = (a | b) - (a & b)
    for d in c:
        new1.append([d])
```

Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: Could you explain how to get the 'greatest common intersection' of two lists?

Comment: try this : `[list(set(o1) & set(o2)) for o1 in old1 for o2 in old2 ]`

Comment: It might just be me, but I can't see how the new list comes from the previous ones? Could you explain some logic behind it?

Comment: @JonClements -- It's not just you ...

Comment: @mgilson thank goodness for that - I know I'm having a "blonde day", (pulling 18 hour days for launch for a new system), so living off coffee at the moment - but *phew* :)

Comment: The new list contains all integers of the old lists and groups them so that the maximal amount of original groups are kept up. Thus, [4,5] from [3,4,5] and [4,5,7], and, likewise [9] and [10] from [9] and [6,8,10].

Comment: @Luigi i think Adrien's answer is fine, if list is not like this: `old1 = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9], [3,11]]`.

Comment: integers are unique, so `...[3,4,5]...[3,11]` cannot be input

Comment: @Luigi check my answer too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

personally, i would first use the set intersection to compute each intersection, then add any item which is left over (that is, items appearing on only one of the 2 list):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import functools
>>> 
>>> old1 = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9]]
>>> old2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[6,8,10]]
>>> 
>>> unique1 = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: set(a).union(set(b)),old1)
>>> unique2 = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: set(a).union(set(b)),old2)
>>> new = [list(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a,b in itertools.product(old1,old2) if len(set(a).intersection(set(b))) != 0]
>>> new.extend([x] for x in unique1.symmetric_difference(unique2))
>>> 
>>> new
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [7], [8, 6], [9], [10]]
```

the symetric difference of a and b is equivalent to `(a|b)-(a&b)`, it yields the items which are appear in only one of the 2 sets.

*(of course, you can get some inspiration from Grijesh Chauhan's answer, to simplify the intersection: `new = filter(None, [list(set(a) & set(b)) for a in old1 for b in old2)])`)*

Comment: You have done! :) ..nice I am trying, please read Luigi comment to my answer to be sure.

Comment: i am not sure it is okay: let `old1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]` and `old2 = [[1,2],[5,6]]`, i have the impression that the result should be `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`... with this code, it will yield `[[1,2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]`.

Comment: IMHO, this works perfectly! As neither `[3,4]` nor `[5,6]` appear in both old lists, the code returns only single items `[3],[4],[5],[6]`.

Answer (score 3):

**Intersection of two lists:**

```
>>> filter(None,[list(set(o1) & set(o2)) for o1 in old1 for o2 in old2 ])
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [7], [8, 6]]
```

What is the greatest common?  Why are `[9],[10]` included?

**EDIT**

`Greatest Common Intersection` as described by you.

First convert list of list into list (both `old1` & `ld2`), **2-D list to 1-D list**:

```
>>> e_o1 = reduce(list.__add__, old1)
>>> e_o1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> e_o2 = reduce(list.__add__, old2)
>>> e_o2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 10]
```

Take **Intersection** using `filter()`:

```
>>> new = filter(None,[list(set(o1) & set(o2)) for o1 in old1 for o2 in old2])
```

`new` still incomplete: last step:

Now list **elements either not in** `old1` **or in** `old2`,  create temporary list `tl`:

```
>>> tl=filter(lambda x : x not in e_o1 or x not in e_o2 , set(e_o1) | set(e_o2)) 
>>> tl
[9, 10]
```

now **append element of**  `tl` in `new` list **as list**:

```
>>> filter(lambda x:  new.append([x]) ,tl)
[]
>>> new
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [7], [8, 6], [9], [10]]
```

but still result is similar like *Adrien Plisson* code works:

`old1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]` and `old2 = [[1,2],[5,6]]`,
it will yield `[[1,2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]`

Comment: You're right, 'greatest common' is misleading. What I had in mind was a new list with all elements from the old lists while retaining the maximal amount of old lists' fragments (like [4,5] from [3,4,5] and [4,5,7]. As 9 and 10 appear only in one of the old lists each, they should show up in the new list as seperate items: [9], [10].

Comment: @Luigi `old` means from `old1` ?

Comment: `old` means from both `old1` and `old2`

Comment: you need some ting like `set([1,2,3,4]) - set([2,5])` too!